# carregar registros sem expandir a tabela!

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-datatables, table

bom dia! to com uma dificuldade de carregar os registros em uma tabela sem que ela expanda, ex: tenho uma table com 9000 registros, o que acontece é que ao abrir a pagina da tabela ela demora á carregar os registros com isso ela se estende mostrando todos os 9000 resgistros, para depois de um tempo ela diminuir mostrando apenas 10 linhas é claro assim aparecendo a opção de Next(paginação) para ver outros registros, queria saber como fazer com que ela carregue os registros mais rápido e enquanto esta carregando pode até aparece uma mensagem de carregando...!

o codigo é esse:

index.php

```
<link href="../assets/css/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/js/jquery-1.11.3-jquery.min.js"></script>



 <table cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="example" class="table table-striped table-hover table-responsive">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Codigo</th>
    <th>Nome</th>
    <th>Sobrenome</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
    require_once '../config/dbconfig.php';

    $stmt = $db_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuario ORDER BY idusuario DESC");
    $stmt->execute();
    while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        ?>
        <tr title="Edit" id="<?php echo $row['idusuario']; ?>" class="edit-link" onclick="#">
        <td><?php echo $row['idusuario']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['nomeusuario']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['sobreusuario']; ?></td>
        <!--<td align="center"><a id="<?php /*echo $row['emp_id'];*/ ?>" class="delete-link" href="#" title="Delete">
        <img src="delete.png" width="20px" />-->
        </a></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
    </tbody>
    </table>




<script src="../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/js/datatables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/js/crudUsuario.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable({
    "bProcessing": true,    
    });

    $('#example')
    .removeClass( 'display' )
    .addClass('table table-bordered');
});
</script>
```

desde já, Obrigado!

Comment: Precisas disto: https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html, https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/

Comment: então eu já tentei esse aí, eu coloco o  "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true, o processing não funciona e o server dá erro!

Comment: Tens de ver o que o servidor manda como resposta, se tiveres os erros habilitados no php consegues ver que erro é que está a acontecer

Comment: o erro é esse ao coloca o serverSide (datatables warning table id=example - invalid json response), acredito que pelo fato do php esta no index e nao por via ajax, então não possuo essa linha também ("ajax": "../server_side/scripts/server_processing.php") por que o meu codigo php esta na propria tabela como pode ser observado acima!

Comment: Esse erro é dado já do lado cliente, e (tenho quase a certeza) que provém de um erro que tens do lado servidor. Tens de ir a network  e ver a resposta que o servidor está a mandar: https://postimg.org/image/lyzsc2nz1/ , clicas no lado direito no serviço que está a ser chamado no teu script js das datatables

Comment: seria isso? https://postimg.org/image/frh6ouvbz/

Comment: Não jeferson, é o teu index.php?.... em baixo, aí é que vês a resposta do servidor ao pedido feito para a montagem da datatable

Comment: cara sou leigo nessa parte de js e em algumas configurações que não uso com frequência, o console da esse erro (https://postimg.org/image/i9b9r18zn/) e o index.php carrega tuydo de uma vez e nem diminui os registros mas, com aquele serverside!https://postimg.org/image/3ou6w7e0z/

Comment: Não é esse index.php... É o ultimo em baixo, "index.php?draw=..."

Comment: então, carrega todos os 9000 e aparece os html e a table com todos esses registros... https://postimg.org/image/xrla24shj/

Comment: Isso é o que está mal, não deve haver html nem nada, simplesmente um json enviado pelo servidor, tem em conta este exemplo... https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html na tab ajax e server side, segue-te por isso... O servidor tem de mandar SÓ o que está na tab ajax, um json

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52146/discussion-between-jefferson-androcles-and-miguel).